# Android change listview item text color

Tags: android, listview

i'm trying to change some items text color (or backgroung color) in a list view based on a flag . after a long search i didn't find out how to do it , i'm calling the below loop after specific action to change the color:

```
ListView _listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView2);

        for (int i=0;i<=_listView.getCount();i++)
        {   
           if(Falg == True)
           {
            //here i want to change the list view item color or backgroud color
           }
        }
```

Comment: Hi, get the corresponding liew view element e.g. View element = _listView.getAdapter().getItem(position) and set the color element.setBackgroundColor(Color.rgb(202, 202, 202));

Comment: if you want to customize the layout, i recommend using a custom adapter.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

You can override the getView method of Array adapter and change the color:

```
ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = 
                    new ArrayAdapter<String>(getApplicationContext(), 
                    android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, 
                    myList) {

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

        View view = super.getView(position, convertView, parent);
        TextView text = (TextView) view.findViewById(android.R.id.text1);

        if (flag == True) {
            text.setTextColor(Color.BLACK);
        }   

        return view;
    }
};
```

Comment: the VIewGroup and the flag where did they come from? @AdnanMulla

Comment: flag is a global variable you maintain and viewgroup is passed in the getView method

Comment: after override the getView(), the OnItemClick is not called. my listview only have a textview

Comment: Thats some really good trick and knowledge.. Good stuff @AdnanMulla

Answer (score 4):

You can do it directly in your custom `Adapter`.

See [Adapter.getView()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/Adapter.html#getView%28int,%20android.view.View,%20android.view.ViewGroup%29)

You can inflate row layout in this method and dynamically change view colors and other stuff.

Answer (score 3):

Create a Custom Layout, define your color in that layout.

Like this:

```
<? xml version="1.0" encoding=" utf-8 "? >
<TextView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
 android:id="@+id/tv"
 android:textColor="@color/white"  // Here You define your desired color
 android:layout_width="fill_parent"
 android:gravity="center"
 android:layout_height="fill_parent"/>
```

Use this layout in your adapter, like this:

```
ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(
    this, R.layout.custom_textview, info);
lv.setAdapter(adapter);
```

This way you don't need to use custom adapter.

Answer (score -3):

You can set font color style .... like

```
textView.setText(Html.fromHtml("<b><u>"+string+"<b><u>"));
```

when you populate the text into your listview.