# Items in ListView are hidden and only shown onClick

Tags: android, listview

I know its weird question I have never seen anything like that. I have added elements to `ListView` and I can see they are there because I can see the grey line after each element but I can see only lines and instead text there is just white space. If I click on it and hold I just after that I can see text and orange background.

Any idea why it is happening like that? 
CODE:

```
// list view for questions
    lv = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.questionsLV);
    adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(CustomWindowTitle.this,
            android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, list);
adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
```

Listener for EditText:

```
questionET.setOnEditorActionListener(new OnEditorActionListener() {

@Override
public boolean onEditorAction(TextView v, int actionId,
                KeyEvent event) {
if ((actionId == EditorInfo.IME_ACTION_DONE) || ((event.isShiftPressed() == false)
&& (event.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_ENTER) && (event.getAction() ==  
KeyEvent.ACTION_DOWN))) {
String question = v.getText() + "";
v.setText("");
list.add(question);
refreshListView();
return true;
} else
return false;
}
});
```

Even if I set this up in XML:

```
<ListView
                android:id="@+id/questionsLV"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                android:textColor="#000000" >
            </ListView>
```

Check this for the answer might help to someone: [How to change text color of simple list item](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5563698/how-to-change-text-color-of-simple-list-item)

Comment: what is in refreshListView?

Comment: It's just a method where I do list.notifySetDataChanged();

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create a color.xml file in your values folder with the following contents

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <color name="white">#FFFFFF</color>
    <color name="black">#000000</color>
</resources>
```

Then in your code just after v.setText() method have this line

```
v.setTextColor(R.color.black);
```

I hope this works for you.

Comment: Could you edit your answer by adding this thing with the selector please? I will mark it as answer, thank you.

Comment: Ok question,what is simple_list_item_1? and list.

Comment: list is list where I store the strings, and simple list item is the way how the listview is represented (type of it .. like style or whatever) but I found out that for sure it is color of the text because when I set black bcg then I can see it u are right. But how to change it since in my edit you can see I changed text and no effect.

Comment: I have added it everywhere where I could just for try and it is not working, let me experiment more, but you are right is color of the text so I am gonna mark it as right answer.

Comment: Have a look at this answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20809272/android-change-listview-item-text-color

Answer (score 0):

Did you set the background color of your layout to white? The default android theme is a dark theme that presents white text on a black background, so if you set a white background, you'll end up with white text on a white background.

I would suggest that you change the default theme in your manifest to a theme extending `@android:style/Theme.Light` or `@android:style/Theme.Holo.Light` (for v11+) because these themes provide default values that match a light background, including dark text.